# Pandas Higher timeframe without resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DF with 5min observations.
I'd like to add another column for 1Hr observations of rsi on close price, but using the immediate 60min before the new 5min observation that just came in every 5min. It needs to be updated every 5min. 
Have tried resample but I have a problem when the new data comes in and the 60min is not finished yet, thus I don't want the update on the hour, but every 5min.

Have tried taking the `df['sma60'] = df.close.rolling(window=60)`, but when I apply PYTI rsi I get NAN's.

EDIT:
After the first answer I tried the following but it doesn't look right to me if you look at the graphs below.

```
df['rsiCurrent'] = rsi(df.close, 13)
df['sma15'] = df.close.rolling('15min').mean()
df['rsi15'] = rsi(df.sma15, 13)
df['sma60'] = df.close.rolling('1H').mean()
df['rsi60'] = rsi(df.sma15, 13)
```

[Display the output graphs and you can see it doesn't look right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJkBU.png)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(df[:450]['rsiCurrent'])
plt.legend(['TDI Cur'])
plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(df[:450]['rsi15'])
plt.legend(['TDI 15m'])
plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(df[:450]['rsi60'])
plt.legend(['TDI 60'])
plt.show()
```

The code above for the display but but other than this it is only the close in the DF.

Any direction or correction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if your Dataframe is time indexed (index is datetieme), you can use a time period as window [refer here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)
e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'col2':[1,2,3,4,5]},
                   index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:10:02'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:03'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 10:30:05'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130101 10:40:06')])
>>>df
                     col1  col2
2013-01-01 09:00:00     1     1
2013-01-01 09:10:02     2     2
2013-01-01 09:31:03     3     3
2013-01-01 10:30:05     4     4
2013-01-01 10:40:06     5     5
```

apply window =1H

```
df.col1.rolling('1H').mean()

2013-01-01 09:00:00    1.0
2013-01-01 09:10:02    1.5
2013-01-01 09:31:03    2.0
2013-01-01 10:30:05    3.5
2013-01-01 10:40:06    4.5
```